# hide show custom filter in ng-repeat that uses table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, algorithm

How can I use custom filter to hide inventory column of color pencil special on date 2-10-2017 in the view?

color pencil special's inventory is depends on color pencil's inventory which in this case it's located somewhere.

```
$scope.stationary = [{
    "name": "Pen",
    "data": [{
      "date": "1-10-2017",
      "inventory": 25
    }, {
      "date": "2-10-2017",
      "inventory": 21
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Color Pencil",
    "data": [{
      "date": "1-10-2017",
      "inventory": 3
    }, {
      "date": "2-10-2017",
      "inventory": 0
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Color Pencil Special",
    "data": [{
      "date": "1-10-2017",
      "inventory": 2
    }, {
      "date": "2-10-2017",
      "inventory": 1 // hide this in the view since inventory of color pencil is zero
    }]
  }]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2krrda9k/

I have stuck for this for hours. This is tough..

Answer (score 1):

You can use this custom filter,

```
myApp.filter('match', function() {
  return function(items) {
    debugger;
    var filtered = [];
    var condition = false;
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      angular.forEach(item.data, function(vals) {
        if (vals.inventory == 0 && condition == false) {
          condition = true;
        } else if (vals.inventory != 0 && condition === false) {
          if (filtered.indexOf(item) == '-1') {
            filtered.push(item);
          }

        }
      });
    });
    return filtered;
  };
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/n1g4tdp5/)**

Comment: your fiddle link isn't work, I think you forgot to update.

Comment: strange I did the same thing like yours but doesn't work, what's the problem with my fiddle ealier, curios.

Comment: Tried it, actually this is not correct. I want only hide a column not the entire row. On 1-10-2017, actually should display the inventory because color pencil has stock.